# error "error: expected unqualified-id before 'return' "

Tags: c++, return

I have been working on this, its a really simple program, but it is getting an error

> error: expected unqualified-id before 'return'

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

main(){
    string name;          //here we declare the variables
    string password;      //here we declare the variables
    string new_user;      //here we declare the variables
    string new_name;      //here we declare the variables
    string new_password;  //here we declare the variables
    
    cout<<"Enter your username : ";
    cin>>name;

    if(name == "kinshuk"){
        cout<<"Enter the password ; ";
        cin>>password;
        if(password == "11kk44"){
            cout<<"passwod confirmed,\n Welcome Back !!";
        }
    }
    else{
        cout<<"user not found"<<endl ;
        cout<<"Do you want to make your own accout? :"<<endl ;
        cout<<"(1) yes"<<endl<<"(2) no"<<endl ;
        cin>>new_user ;

        if(new_user == "yes"){
            cout<<"ok then,"<<endl ;
            cout<<"Enter the name you want sign in with : "<<endl ;
            cin>>new_name;
            cout<<"Enter the password"<<endl;
            cin>>new_password;
            
            cout<<"now you can sign in :)"<<endl;
            cout<<"Enter your name : "<<endl;
            cin>>name;

            if(name == new_name){
                cout<<"Enter your password : "<<endl;
                cin>>password;
                
                if(password == new_password){
                    cout<<"Welcome !!" ;
                }
                if(password != new_password){
                    cout<<"User not found" ;
                
                }
            if(name != new_name){
                cout<<"user not found : "<<endl ;
            }                
            }
        if(new_user == "no"){}
            cout<<"ok :)" ;
        }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should make sure all of you code is formatted correctly, You should also include details in the body of the question, and the title should be simple but informative of the problem (and not the whole question).

Comment: `main` needs to return an `int` and you have a mismatch between the number of `{` and `}`. If you fix those, it will compile just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has an erroneous `}` that you need to remove:

```cpp
if(new_user == "no"){} // <-- REMOVE } HERE
    cout<<"ok :)" ;
}
```

Also, `main()` is missing a return type:

```cpp
int main(){ // <-- ADD int HERE
```